# Why Docker needs the --device flag?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

One of the options I can pass to `docker run` is `--device`, as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container---device). I wonder, if everything-is-a-file™ is Unix/Linux, why Docker needs a special way of binding devices to the container?
My understanding is that creating a volume bind should be enough. Then, I could mount some `/dev/deviceX` file to some file in my container (like `/mydeviceX`) and access it that way. In the end, all the operations on `/mydeviceX` from within the container would be relied to the `/dev/deviceX` on the host, wouldn't they?

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container---device ? Doesn't the option do something more than just "files"?

Comment: @KamilCuk Are you referring to the fact that I can access the devices without `--privileged` and that I can control access with `:rwm`? Does it mean that actually, I could bind the device files into the container using "normal" volume mount as well? In such case, I'd of course have to take care of proper permissions for the user ID that the container is using.

Comment: If you could `mknod` a device-special file to mount the host's root disk, you could trivially escape the container and root the host; the `--device` option prevents attacks like this.